# Add a column with partially matching pattern from a different file

Tags: bash, terminal, pattern-matching, paste, data-manipulation

I have two files with similar structure (tab-delimited and many, many lines, column 3 minus column 2 = 1) that look somewhat like this:

File 1:

```
1 170023 170024 A -
1 170024 170025 T -
1 170026 170027 A -
1 170028 170029 G -
1 170029 170030 C -
1 170031 170032 C -
```

File 2:

```
1 170023 170024 A
1 170024 170025 T
1 170025 170026 G
1 170026 170027 A
1 170027 170028 G
1 170028 170029 T
1 170029 170030 A
1 170030 170031 G
1 170031 170032 C
```

I want to add column 4 from File 2 (the letters only column) to File 1. This would, in general, be very easy with `pr` or `paste` but the problem is that columns 1-3 are not the same in the two files. In other words, the files have different numbers of lines and File 2 has always more lines than File 1 (in particular, all numbers in columns 2 and 3 found in File 1 also occur in File 2, but not *vice versa*). I would also know how to do it in R but the files are too big to be easily handled in R and I will need to do the task for more than a dozen of files. So I guess, bash or any command line software would be the most efficient to solve this.

What I exactly want to do is add the letter of column 4 from File 2 if and only if columns 1-3 in File 2 match columns 1-3 in File 1 exactly. Thereby, it does not matter what symbol occurs in columns 4 and 5 of File 1. Based on the examples of File 1 and File 2 above, the desired output would be:

Output:

```
1 170023 170024 A - A
1 170024 170025 T - T
1 170026 170027 A - A
1 170028 170029 G - T
1 170029 170030 C - A
1 170031 170032 C - C
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me with this. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think and provide a simple solution using `join` and `awk` for this. May not be the most efficient ways of solving it with `awk` (might get bashed from experts for this :)), but I was able to solve this.

**Solution-1:-**

All you need to do is to first use `join` without specifying any particular columns to join on. It automatically joins files based on the common recurring column which is column 1 in this case. Then on that output, we can let `awk` play to print those lines that match to your need and format the required columns.

```
join file1 file2 | awk '{ if (($2==$6) && ($3==$7)) printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $8) }'
```

produced me the output as

```
1 170023 170024 A - A
1 170024 170025 T - T
1 170026 170027 A - A
1 170028 170029 G - T
1 170029 170030 C - A
1 170031 170032 C - C
```

**Solution-2:-**

Using only plain `join`

```
join -j 2 file1 file2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.4
```

will also produce the same output as you expected.

```
`join' writes to standard output a line for each pair of input lines that have identical join fields.
```

Am quoting the `man` page contents for `join` as below

```
`-j FIELD'
     Equivalent to `-1 FIELD -2 FIELD'.

`-o FIELD-LIST'

 Otherwise, construct each output line according to the format in
 FIELD-LIST.  Each element in FIELD-LIST is either the single
 character `0' or has the form M.N where the file number, M, is `1'
 or `2' and N is a positive field number.
```

So the command works first by join `file1` and `file2` by column 2 and printing the required columns from the output seen, indicated by (`1.1`,`1.2`,`1.3`,`1.4`,`1.5`,`2.4`) which should be read as `file`.`column`. For a better understanding, I suggest see the output without the `-o` option first and how I am constructing the output from what is seen.

**Solution-3:-**

Using plain'ol `awk`, I actually learnt a bit of it myself while answering this question.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$4;next} (($1 FS $2 FS $3) in a) {print $0, a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]}' file2 file1
```

Explanation:-

1. `FNR==NR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$4;next}` will process on `file2` storing the entries of the array `a` with subscript as column1 space column2 space column3 and value as column4.
2. Now on `file1`, We need to match those rows from `file2` from the array by doing `(($1 FS $2 FS $3) in a) {print $0, a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]}` which will give me all those rows (we need value of column4) in `file1` whose subscript is same as one from `file2`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still running the analyses (many big files) and will edit this comment to report how it worked out.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge: That would be helpful!

Comment: As I had tab-delimited files and the new column should also be tab-delimited, I used the following command based on your third solution: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3]=$4;next} (($1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3) in a) {print $0 "\t" a[$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3]}' file2 file1`. Again, thank you!